# Поменять способ выделения текста с блока на строки

Tags: android-studio, ide

Я сам не понял как это получилось, но курсор стал работать не так как надо. Если начать выделять строки, то курсор выделяет именно тот квадрат который я отмечаю, а не полностью строки которые попадают под курсор. (Надеюсь понятно описал)
Помогите пожалуйста вернуть все в нормальное состояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Режим блочного выделения включается и выключается комбинацеий <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> или в меню Edit - Column Selection Mode.